# ogr2ogr gml file loaded but not in the database

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to import gml files to postgres by following the steps on [AstunTechnology/Loader](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader)

`loader.config` file is updated as;

`ogr_cmd=ogr2ogr --config GML_EXPOSE_FID NO -append -skipfailures -f PostgreSQL PG:'dbname=postgres active_schema=public host=data01 user=postgres password=123456789' $file_path`

The `python loader.py loader.config` file execute successfully as,

```
Config: {'tmp_dir': 'U:/Data/AB/data/Temp1', 'out_dir': 'U:/Data/AB/data/Temp', 'gfs_file': '../gfs/osmm_topo_postgres.gfs', 'ogr_cmd': "ogr2ogr --config GML_EXPOSE_FID NO -append -skipfailures -f PostgreSQL PG:'dbname=postgres active_schema=public host=data01 user=postgres password=123456789' $file_path", 'post_cmd': '', 'debug': 'True', 'src_dir': 'U:/Data/AB/data', 'prep_cmd': 'python prepgml4ogr.py $file_path prep_osgml.prep_osmm_topo'}
Processing: U:/Data/AB/data\AddressBasePremium_FULL_2019-09-12_001.gml
Prepared file: U:/Data/AB/data/Temp1\tmp8aypa_\AddressBasePremium_FULL_2019-09-12_001
Prep command: python prepgml4ogr.py U:/Data/AB/data\AddressBasePremium_FULL_2019-09-12_001.gml prep_osgml.prep_osmm_topo
Loading: U:/Data/AB/data\AddressBasePremium_FULL_2019-09-12_001.gml
OGR command: ogr2ogr --config GML_EXPOSE_FID NO -append -skipfailures -f PostgreSQL PG:dbname=postgres active_schema=public host=data01 user=postgres password=123456789 U:/Data/AB/data/Temp1\tmp8aypa_\AddressBasePremium_FULL_2019-09-12_001
Loaded 1 file
```

However I cannot see a table created in the `public` schema. Am I missing something here? I believe the table name would be similar to the file name.

Comment: It's not best practice to load user data as the `postgres` user, and it's *bad* practice to load user data in the `postgres` database.  You should always create a database, and login roles, and schemas to manage your data.

Comment: -append tries to add data into existing table but I am not sure what happens if table does not exist. Take it away in any case if you do not want to append.

Comment: @user30184 did you mean that I should create the tables before running `ogr2ogr `?

Comment: No, read https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html, about option `-append
Append to existing layer instead of creating new`. Without -append a new table should be created automatically. If it still fails there is some other issue. I recommend to test the ogr2ogr command first from the command line before adding Python to the play.

Comment: I did try using `ogr2ogr` on `OSGeo4W shell` but getting this [error posted here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340730/ogr2ogr-error-1-couldnt-fetch-requested-layer)